# When can you perform the same operation on both sides of an equality?

Tags: abstract-algebra

It is clear that if $ac=bc$ then $acc^{-1}=bcc^{-1}$. But when we try to multiply matrices things get a little bit more complicated. For example if $AC=BC$ then $ACC^{-1}=BCC^{-1}$ is not always true. Why is that? I think it has something to do with non-injective mapping, or rather... non-*half*-injective mapping? For example, there are different $a,b,c,d$ such that $ab=cd$, but there are no different $a,b$ such that $ac=bc$. What is this property called?

Comment: If all the entities exist with their usual meaning, then the statement $AC=BC\implies ACC^{-1}=BCC^{-1}$ is true.

Comment: @GitGud There is, however, an innate assumption of associativity in the notation $ACC^{-1}$, so it is not necessarily true in the absence of all other assumptions beyond basic logic. $a\circ b=c\circ d$ implies $(a\circ b)\circ e=(c\circ d)\circ e$, but not $(e\circ a)\circ b=(e\circ c)\circ d$ (where $\circ$ is an unspecified binary operation).

Comment: @MarioCarneiro associativity is not what you wrote

Comment: @Avitus You're correct - I'm *not* assuming associativity. If $\circ$ is associative, then $(e\circ a)\circ b=e\circ (a\circ b)=e\circ (c\circ d)=(e\circ c)\circ d$, and so the identity is true in this case.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro If (a*c)=(b*c), then [(a*c)*d)]=[(b*c)*d].  However, if (a*c)=(b*c), it does not necessarily follow that [a*(c*d)]=[b*(c*d)], *unless* "*" associates.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Yes, that's exactly the content of my first comment.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro No, it's not the content of your first comment (though I guess that you intended to convey such).  You said "There is, however, an innate assumption of associativity in the notation $ACC^{−1}$..."  The notation $ACC^{−1}$ doesn't imply that the binary operation associates.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood The assumption of associativity is in the equality $(ab)c=abc=a(bc)$. It is possible to use the notation $abc$ without assuming associativity, say by always indicating left-associativity $(ab)c=abc\ne a(bc)$, but then you get the confusing statement that $ab=cd$ implies $abe=cde$, but not $eab=ecd$ (which is why I wrote the first comment that way, with $e$ on the left - if you assume left associativity, placing $e$ on the left is not a legal manipulation if you want to preserve equality).

Comment: Although programmers frequently use notation $a\circ b\circ c$ for non-associative operations (as in `a/b/c`), I think it is fair to say that this practice is almost universally avoided in mathematics, when this sort of "string" notation is only ever used when the operation is known to be associative. That is why I refer to an "innate assumption" regarding associativity.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro If abc means [(ab)c], then if ab=cd, then abe=cde, but eab=ecd is false in general.  If abc means a(bc), then if ab=cd, then eab=ecd, but abe=cde is false in general.  I don't see how either is anymore confusing than suppressing any symbol for a binary operation.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood The confusion comes not from suppressing the operation symbol, but from suppressing the parentheses indicating the order of operations in a context where guessing wrong will cause an incorrect statement. By removing the parentheses, the notation suggests a symmetry that doesn't exist, which is dangerous and error-prone, which is why we never do it except when the symmetry actually *does* exist.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I didn't claim that suppressing the operation symbol causes the confusion.  But, NO, the confusion does not come from suppressing parentheses which indicate the order of operations.  If ab=cd, then eab=eab.  Now replace ab with cd on the right hand side of "eab=eab" and we obtain eab=ecd.  Likewise we could obtain abe=cde.  Now I have NOT presupposed that eab means (ea)b NOR have I presupposed that eab means e(ab), it could mean either one, I have no idea which one it means.  How does the confusion arise?  It arises from suppressing the parentheses implicit in ab=cd.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro And no, the problem doesn't here doesn't have anything to do with a lack of symmetry suggested by the notation.  Consider the equation [x#(y^z)]=[(x#y)^z] where "#" and "^" each indicate some binary operation.  Now associativity is a special case of that equation where #=^.  We could have a convention that abc means [a#(b$c)].  How has the notation "abc" suggested such a symmetry in such a case?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood As far as I am concerned, that is an even worse convention. In that case you are using the *same* symbol (adjacency) to denote two *different* operations. I'm not saying it is incorrect; you are free to define whatever conventions you like, but there is such a thing as a *bad convention*, and that definitely qualifies. The only time I would accept anything like that is if it is really a 3-argument operation, in which case writing $abcd$ would be absolutely disallowed, due to ambiguity in which operations are being applied.

Comment: The "symmetry" of the notation "$abc$" is completely independent of whether it means $(a\circ b)\circ c$ or $a\#(b\$c)$ or anything else; it is a property of the notation itself, not the notation's meaning. Using a "symmetric" notation for an asymmetric operation (i.e. not associative or with different operations applied at left and right) is an invitation to trouble and misunderstanding and a very bad convention.

Answer (score 3):

I think that in any mathematical structure if $a = b$, and $f(a)$ is uniquely defined then $f(a) = f(b)$ whatever $f$ is.

Comment: Note that $f(a)$ may not be necessarily uniquely defined, even in such a simple case as this: $AC=BC\implies ACC^{-1}=BCC^{-1}$ is not well defined if $C$ is not invertible.

Comment: @Mario Carneiro: yes, the function must be defined and as you say in this case $C$ must be invertible. The uniqueness aspect is something else: suppose that there is a mathematical representation of a die, and two dice $D1$ and $D2$ are equivalent, and in this sense $D1 = D2$. If $f$ is a function that rolls a die (i.e. returns a random number 1 to 6), then I don't think I can write $f(D1) = f(D2)$ ? Is there a better example ?

Comment: However, does 1.0 in domain $\mathbb R$ equal 1 in domain $\mathbb N$? I can do operations on the former (like divide by 2) that I cannot do on the latter.

Comment: @MARXOS To say that $a = b$ would generally imply that they are elements in the same object. You can have an injection $\phi: \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ and now $\phi(1 \in \mathbb N) = 1 \in \mathbb R$ but you can't strictly speaking say that $1 \in \mathbb N = 1 \in \mathbb R$

Comment: @TomCollinge:  To "imply they are elements of the same object" implies that philosophy and metaphysics of math has developed in which such use of the word "object" (and "elements of") makes sense and the use of the symbol "=" is properly defined.  I use the term "domain" for the former.  For the latter, I find a rather too ambiguous, but I haven't nailed it down sufficiently to offer more myself.

Answer (score 1):

It goes wrong if you disregard the importance of left and right multiplication, i.e. as you stated, in $\mathbb{R}$ if $ac=bc$, then $acc^{-1}=bcc^{-1}=c^{-1}bc$, this all holds because multiplication is commutative in $\mathbb{R}$ i.e. $ab=ba$ always holds.

This does not hold for matrices in general i.e $AB\neq BA$ so if $AC=BC$ holds, then $ACC^{-1}=BCC^{-1}$ is true but $C^{-1}AC=BCC^{-1}$ is not true in general.

The property you are looking for such that $ac=bc\Rightarrow a=b$ is called the **cancellation law**, it is present in any ring with no zero divisors, i.e. there are no $a,b$ s.t $ab=0$.

Hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

"For example if AC=BC then $ACC^{-1}=BCC^{-1}$ is not always true."

It isn't clear to me if this is true or false.  It could always qualify as true depending on the convention of the author.  The difficulty lies in that we don't know what a#b#c means for an arbitrary binary operation "#".  Does it mean [(a#b)#c] or does it mean [a#(b#c)]?

If abc consists of a shorthand for [(a#b)#c], then if (a#c)=(b#c), we have the following:

```
 1. [(a#c]#d]=[(a#c)#d] since everything is equal to itself.
```

Now replacing (a#c) with (b#c) on the right hand side only in 1. we obtain

```
 2. [(a#c]#d]=[(b#c)#d].
```

Thus, given the shorthand here, if AC=BC then $ACC^{-1}=BCC^{-1}$.

However, if abc consists of a shorthand for [a#(b#c)], then $ACC^{-1}=BCC^{-1}$ means

$[A#(C#C^{-1})]=[B#(C#C^{-1})]$.  If (a#b)=(b#c) and # associates, then $ACC^{-1}=BCC^{-1}$.  However, the if-then statement doesn't hold in general if # does not associate, as the last equality I hope makes clear enough.